# How to make your SQL data available for people without database access?

Tags: postgresql, view

I have several report views that are relevant for a few people that have no SQL knowledge so I guess the best solution would be to put them on a website. Surely data sharing must be a common thing to do for SQL experts

Without using tableau, how to have these views available to be visualized on an internal website and/or downloadable in the form of a csv file?

Database is postgresql. Any solution is fine as long as it can be simple for the end user

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export data, the simpler is to user the `copy` sql command.
For example, if you want to export all data in a view names view1, you could perform:

```
copy 
  (
    select *
    from view1
  )
to 'complete_filename.csv'
with format csv;
```

Then you can use a scheduler or a scheduled task to copy this(ose) file(s) into a network share directory (or publish them on a website).

You'll find more informations about `copy` here : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html